# TCP socket programming error

Tags: c, sockets

Learning socket programming, and the following is the cut/paste of error parts.

FYI, I was following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/printversion.cgi?tutorial=unix_sockets&file=socket_client_example.htm).

Undrestood `gethostbyname()` returns `struct hostent`

```
struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *name);
```

with the following code.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <sys/types.h>
  3 #include <sys/socket.h>
  4 #include <netinet/in.h>
  5 #include <stdlib.h>
  6 #include <strings.h>
  7 
  8 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  9 {
 10     int sockfd, portno, n;
 11     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
 12     struct hostent *server;
 13 
 14     server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
 15 
 16     /* compose serv_addr */
 17     bzero( (char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) );
 18     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 19     bcopy( (char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
 20     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
 21 
 22     return 0;
 23 }
```

I have the following gcc error/warning

```
$gcc client2.c
client2.c: In function ‘main’:
client2.c:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
client2.c:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
client2.c:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Please point me what I m doing wrong?

Comment: Turning all compiler warnings on using `-Wall` helps ...

Comment: Also: `gethostbyame()` and `gethostbyaddr()` are somehow deprecated. You might better use `getnameinfo()` and `getaddrinfo()`.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding this to the top:

```
#include <netdb.h>
```

It's a required include for `gethostbyname`. If you type `man gethostbyname` at the command line, you'll get the man page, which opens:

[image: Screenie of "gethostbyname(3)" manpage.]

The manpages detail which headers you need to include (under **SYNOPSIS**).

(Hit <kbd>q</kbd> to exit `man`.)

Comment: +1. Though it would be nice to elaborate on C, include files and how did you come up with that `netdb.h`. Perhaps at least mentioning `man gethostbyname` would be good...

Comment: @VladLazarenko: thanks for the feedback! Have added some information on the manpage lookup :)

Answer (score 5):

Note in the `bzero(3)` manpage:

```
   4.3BSD.  This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in
   POSIX.1-2001): use memset(3) in new programs.  POSIX.1-2008
   removes the specification of bzero().
```

You should definitely use `memset(3)` instead of `bzero(3)` -- the API is only slightly more verbose but that's not entirely horrible. Same story for `bcopy(3)` and `memcpy(3)`.

`memset(3)` and `memcpy(3)` are in `<string.h>`, not `<strings.h>`, so change that too.

You're using too many casts in your code; when the prototype for a function includes `void *`, it'll accept any pointer type as a parameter and the compiler will correctly track the types. Adding a cast will tell the compiler that you know better -- and will, quite often, *mask* actual errors and warnings.

Also note that `gethostbyname(3)` requires the `<netdb.h>` header, too.

With these changes in place, your code compiles with fewer warnings:

```
$ CFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra" make client2
cc -Wall -Wextra    client2.c   -o client2
client2.c: In function ‘main’:
client2.c:11:25: warning: unused variable ‘n’ [-Wunused-variable]
client2.c:11:9: warning: unused variable ‘sockfd’ [-Wunused-variable]
client2.c:9:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
client2.c:21:31: warning: ‘portno’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

(None of them should be a surprise; it's code in progress. Good on you for trying to build the code slowly...)